# How assign a a value from application.properties to a @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to assign a value with the name of the @Service from application.properties tu |@Qualifier . I tried but it doesn't work .

In fact i have two services which implement the same interface and i would like to change the service from application.properties

Someone has any idea how to do this?

this is my code

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



@RestController
public class Controler {


    @Qualifier("${service.name}")
    @Autowired
    private InterfaceTest interfaceTest;


    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return interfaceTest.test();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that in the constructor of this controller by using `Environment` and `ApplicationContext` beans.

Just remove `Autowired` annotation from fields and accept other parameters through constructor as well.

```
public Controller(Environment environment, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    String serviceName = environment.getProperty("service.name");
    this.interfaceTest = applicationContext.getBean(serviceName, InterfaceTest.class);
}
```

Those bean qualifiers and other annotations of spring just except literals as far as I know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have a error `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controler' defined in file [C:\Users\MARIAN\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\Controler.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed;`

Comment: I think you didn't remove @Autowired annotation from field. Can you share your code please?

Comment: `@RestController
public class Controler {


    public Controler(Environment environment, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        String property = environment.getProperty("service.name");
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) applicationContext;
        this.interfaceTest = applicationContext.getBean(property, InterfaceTest.class);
    }

    @Qualifier("${service.name}")
    private InterfaceTest interfaceTest;


    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return interfaceTest.test();
    }
}`

Comment: you can use this @RestController
public class Controler {
    public Controller(Environment environment, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        String serviceName = environment.getProperty("service.name");
        this.interfaceTest = applicationContext.getBean(serviceName, InterfaceTest.class);
    }

    private InterfaceTest interfaceTest;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return interfaceTest.test();
    }
}